# Display JSON or XML data on Freeboard(Web Dashboard)

Tags: xml, json, xively, node-red

I am developing an iOT system for my school project.

I have this setup with a DHT11 Temp/Humidity Sensor and a Raspberry-Pi(with Node-Red)

I am able to get data from the sensor by using Nodes on Node-Red ,and I can send those data to Xively.

**The Question is I want to display the data from Xively on a free web dashboard.(Freeboard,etc.)**

(I have written some C# pages to connect with Xively to activate/deactivate the sensor and view the statistics on my laptop.)
**I am able to convert the sensor's data to JSON or XML through Node-Red.**

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions to my problem.

1. Connect Freeboard with Node-Red on your device

https://gist.github.com/dceejay/fb47301b759222e05f84

2. Connect Freeboard directly with a datasource (Xively, Local-Harddive ,etc)

http://buglabs.tumblr.com/post/96482541531/using-the-freeboard-tm-json-datasource-with-third-party

(For the second method, I guess there's a bug in Freeboard where the value is not updated regularly.
Link to my Issue request on Github : https://github.com/Freeboard/freeboard/issues/55 
I will update about this matter ASAP.

Update : 
Freeboard have solved this issue.